# Dict column output to standard pandas column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a situation where my output from a previous code step has been stored as a dictionary but as a pandas column after the use of zip function.
Now I want to store the results of this dict column as a standard pandas column.

The code that I have used which has created the dict column using the zip function :

```
a=pd.DataFrame(zip(tf_lst,results),columns=['A','B'])
```

The output from this code looks like this :

```
A             B
Uni.      {'architecture': 0.665, 'software': 0.614}
School    {'Science': 0.665, 'C++': 0.614}
```

Now I want to store the COL B which is currently in the form of a dict to a standard pandas column in the following way:
I want to remove the values from each of the keys and store it separated by commas

```
 A          B              
Uni        architecture,software
School     Science,C++
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use transform: I used assign just in case you want to maintain your original column. You can overwrite it, or even drop it. etc

```
df.assign(C = df.B.transform(','.join))
        A                                           B                      C
0    Uni.  {'architecture': 0.665, 'software': 0.614}  architecture,software
1  School            {'Science': 0.665, 'C++': 0.614}            Science,C++
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error : RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

Comment: In this code there is no recursion used. Can you try `df.B.transform(','.join)` what does that give you?

Comment: Now it gives me. : TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found

Comment: @Django0602 sorry just realized you named your dataframe as `a` and i used `df` sorry for the confusion